# Union of family of connected subsets of a space is a conected space

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

"Let $(A_i){i\in I}$ be a family of connected subsets of a space $X$ with a non-empty intersection. The set $\bigcup{i\in I} A_i$ is connected.

Here is my attempt

\textbf{Proof:} Suppose that $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$ is not connected, which implies that there exist two open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ that form a separation of $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i$. Since each $A_i$ is connected, it follows that $A_i \subset U$ or $A_i \subset V$ for each $i \in I$. Without loss of generality, we can assume that $A_1 \subset U$. As per the hypothesis, $\bigcap_{i\in I} A_i \neq \emptyset$, which implies that $A_i \subset U$ for all $i \in I$. Therefore, $V =
 \emptyset $, leading to a contradiction. Thus, $U$ and $V$ cannot form a separation of $\bigcup_{i\in I} A_i. \text{Consequently, } \bigcup_{i\in I} A_i \text{ is connected.}$

I would like to know if this proof is good or if I make something wrong

Comment: Instead of \textbf{xxx} use **xxx**. See https://math.stackexchange.com/help/formatting. And your proof is correct. Trust yourself!